# Controller action ending in "path" not being reached by request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, ruby-on-rails-5.1

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why my controller is not making an SQL call and then passing that to the view.

In every other part of my application, including other methods in this same controller, no worries. But for whatever reason I can't get this right.

**app/controllers/referrals_controller.rb**

```
class ReferralsController < ApplicationController

    def index # <- This works fine. 
        @referrals = Referral.all
        @referral = Referral.first 
        @reminder = Reminder.first 
        respond_to(:js, :html)
    end 

    def category_path # <- This doesn't work
        @referrals = Referral.where(:category => :option)
        @referral = @referrals.first 
        respond_to :js 
    end 

    def fetch_content # <- This works fine. 
        @referral = Referral.find(params[:follow_id])
        respond_to :js 
    end 
    ...
end
```

**Config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :referrals

  get '/referrals' => 'referrals#index'
  get '/category_path' => 'referrals#category_path', as: 'category'
  get '/fetch_content' => 'referrals#fetch_content', as: 'fetch_content'
end
```

Here are the parts of my view that call those routes.

**app/views/referrals/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Immigration Referral', category_path(:option => 'Immigration Referral'), remote: true, class: 'category-links' %> - 
...
<%= link_to referral.title, fetch_content_path(:follow_id => referral.id), remote: true %>
```

Despite the fact that both `category_path` and `fetch_content` are setup virtually the same, `fetch_content` works perfectly, and `category_path` doesn't even make an SQL query. Where I use `fetch_content` the logs show

```
Started GET "/fetch_content?follow_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-24 09:22:16 -0600
Processing by ReferralsController#fetch_content as JS
  Parameters: {"follow_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Referral Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "referrals".* FROM "referrals" WHERE "referrals"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering referrals/fetch_content.js.erb
  Rendered referrals/_content.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered referrals/fetch_content.js.erb (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

However, when I used `category_path` This is the result:

```
Started GET "/category_path?option=Immigration+Referral" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-24 09:22:22 -0600
Processing by ReferralsController#category_path as JS
  Parameters: {"option"=>"Immigration Referral"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering referrals/category_path.js.erb
  Rendered referrals/_titles.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered referrals/_content.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered referrals/category_path.js.erb (32.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 80ms (Views: 62.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

And in my view `@referrals.nil?` is returning `true`, which I would expect if it's not making an SQL call. My question then, is WHY?! Why is my controller not making an SQL call. I even tried to change to something more simple like `@referrals = Referral.all` but that still doesn't trigger a SQL call. What's happening?

Comment: To access the option being sent, you must do it from the params, try `Referral.where(category: params[:option])`, what do you get?

Comment: Well, as I had stated at the end of the post, I've tried doing something simple like `referral = Referral.all` and nothing happens.

Comment: I would avoid to name action with names ending with path as it clashes with rails routes

Comment: Just rename your action category_path to anything else, Rails should be giving you a warning or error in that such action method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the suffix "path" isn't valid for any action within the controllers, maybe because it should clash with routes Rails manages as pointed out for @apneadiving.

If you set an action with the suffix path, and try to list the action methods for that controller, you'll see that action doesn't exist:

```
class ReferralsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def category_path # <- This doesn't work
    ...
  end 

  def fetch_content_path # <- This works fine. 
    ...
  end 
end
```

The controller has two actions finishing with `*_path`. Now asking for action methods you get:

```
ReferralsController.action_methods
=> #<Set: {"new", "index", "update", "create", "edit", "destroy", "show"}>
```

What happens if you remove the last "h" character in the action name?:

```
ReferralsController.action_methods
=> #<Set: {"new", "index", "update", "create", "edit", "destroy", "show", "category_pat"}>
```

The action appears there, that's why your fetch_content action can be reached and the category one doesn't. Solution is just to rename the action method.

Comment: Yep! This was exactly what was wrong. Thank you so much.